# How extract ZIP archive

Tags: c++, zip

Help me extract the files from the zip archive.
Tried using zlib, but is not compiled minizip.
Wanted try LZMA, but could not connect to the project.
I use VS C++ 2010.

Thank you.

Comment: Try: [zlib](http://zlib.net/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with Windows-only solution, I find [XZip](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4135/XZip-and-XUnzip-Add-zip-and-or-unzip-to-your-app-w) to be very easy to use. You only need to add XUnzip.h/.cpp to your project, nothing else, no other dependencies.

There is also [miniz](https://code.google.com/p/miniz/), which is portable, but I haven't tried it (yet).

Answer (score 0):

As far as a i know LZMA can handle whole zip archives, zlib instead can only uncompress the contained data. A zip archive is a collection of compressed files. So you need to parse the archive, before you can uncompress the contained data chunks (files). Have a look at the file format description on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29).

Answer (score 0):

With zlib you can do something like this:

```
#define ZLIB_WINAPI
#include <zlib.h>
#include <contrib\minizip\unzip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "zlibwapi.lib")


bool decompress(void* dest, unsigned long* pcbDest, const void* src, size_t cbSrc)
{
    return uncompress((Bytef*)dest, pcbDest, (const Bytef*)src, cbSrc) == Z_OK;
}
```

See also working example of wrapper classes for Gilles Volant's Zip/Unzip API at [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4288/Win32-Wrapper-classes-for-Gilles-Volant-s-Zip-Unzi)